# Angular 17 not rendering a component with Socket.io

Tags: angular, rendering, angular-services, socket.io-client

I have the following Angular component, whose only property is an instance of *ConnectionService* service:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ConnectionService } from './connection.service';
//import { inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  // is the same with conn = inject(ConnectionService)
  constructor(private conn: ConnectionService) {}
  ...
}
```

The corresponding template in './app.component.html' is:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div> Site id: <input placeholder="Insert a value"> <button > SET </button> </div>
    <textarea #myTextarea cols="40" rows="5"> </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code of *ConnectionService* service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket, io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { ServerToClientsEvent, ClientToServerEvent, OTSocketClient } from '../../../../Server/typings';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConnectionService {
  socket: Socket<ServerToClientsEvent, ClientToServerEvent>;
  client!: OTSocketClient;
  constructor() {
    this.socket = io("http://localhost:3002/");
    this.socket.on("connect", () => {
      this.connectionService.client = new OTSocketClient(this.socket);
      console.log(`Client ${this.socket.id} connected`);
      this.connectionService.client.askDoc();
    })
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I start the application with **ng serve** the component's html is not rendered and the page keeps loading endlessly. It is probably due to the presence of Socket.io library, even if adding some **console.log** I can see that the connection is successful and also **emit** and **on** methods work successfully.

In the beginning my code for component was:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

let socket = io("http://localhost:3002/");
let client = new OTSocketClient(socket);
socket.on("connect", () => {
   console.log(`Client ${socket.id} connected`);
   client.askDoc();
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
  ...
}
```

and the template was rendered, but I can't know with certainty when the code before class declaration is executed so was suggested to me to insert the code in the **constructor** or in **ngInit()** method but I found the same problem I talked about above. For this reason I tried to add a Service but error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I created a method in my service initiateSocket() which then I have called it from component after view init. It makes sure that you are connecting to socket only when required.